# Is it OK to add tags to questions when the answer suggests so?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

*Introduction: I created a new tag and am now looking at some previous questions which could be enriched with this tag.*

I found a question with the tag `iptables`. The answer suggests not to use `iptables` but `ebtables`. The tag `ebtables` did not exist at the time the question was created and anyway we can assume that the OP did not know about `ebtables` either (since the question is self-answered).

**Is it appropriate to revisit the question and add a tag which is derived from the answer?** My rationale for that would be to help someone searching for a similar question (probably because the "Similar Question" frame may be derived from tags as well as from the content?)

Answer (score 13):

As other answers have noted, *generally* this is a bad idea.

Of course, there are exceptions...

In particular, in questions where an answer successfully identifies the key topic of the question (perhaps based on implicit information), and it appears the asker simply didn't know how to tag properly... You should add the relevant tags to make the question easier to find in the future for others sharing the problem.

A common case would be someone asking a question about mysql but merely tagging it "sql" or "php" or even "wordpress". In such cases, you're not really tagging based on an *answer* so much as you're relying on the expertise in an answer to help clarify the *question*. And **tags should always describe the question.**

Answer (score 8):

I think that this may vary by site and I would encourage you to ask on the site this occurred on. I don't know what they'd do on Stack Overflow or AU but I do know that, on Movies & TV the rule is to *not* add tags that are introduced in answers. Tags should only reflect the question.

So, as an example, if someone asks an ID question looking for a the title of the film and that question is answered and the answer is accepted, it is *against* M&TV policy to add the film's title tag to the question.

So, in your case, if the question is not **about** ebtables, it just happens that an answer recommends using them, that doesn't make the ebtables tag appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to think in terms of the *dependencies* between a question and a set of answers to that question, it's clear that each answer should depend solely on the question and the question should never depend on any of the answers.

Since a tag forms part of a question, adding tags to a question in response to answers is therefore not an appropriate thing to do.

You also risk of invalidating other answers if you do that. It could even be construed as an attempt to reply to a question within a question!

I believe this applies to all Stack Exchange sites.